# linking to multiple sencha touch applications

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

My organization is getting into mobile development. I'd like to have 1 icon on the iPad screen which loads up a dashboard. This will be a sort of launcher application.
The dashboard will have icons linking to all our applications. Is this approach possible with Sencha Touch? I don't think including every controller, view and model in the Ext.application declaration is the right way to go because it would use up too much memory. Can/should I manually instantiate required components as needed instead?

Also, as new applications are developed I want to be able to add them to the dashboard without much fuss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best for each of your 'applications' to be actual Sencha Touch applications. They can each be in their own project directory/URL. The `index` can be a very simple Sencha Touch application, or even just a HTML file (with some CSS to spruce it up and make it *app-like*), which has a bunch of links to each of your applications.

You could build all this into one application, but the project is going to get huge overtime, and the loading time and instantiation time will get out of control.

Comment: when I package these applications for the device wouldn't they be like native iPad applications? I'm wondering how I can link to them -- is there a concept of a webroot?

Comment: @artfuldodger PhoneGap has a WWW directory, so you can follow rdougan's advice and then split off sub-apps into www/app1 www/app2 and etc.  With someone overrides to Ext.Loader you could have common code in www/lib or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Kent Uni sencha touch site....I think it is on GitHub. Very useful for learning, in that app there is a dashboard that takes you to new pages. It's sencha touch 1 I think but still cool.

:-)